# Insert html tag to a Database as a String and retrieve it back and show the html

Tags: c#, sql, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to insert html tag to a Database as a String and retrieve it back. after retrieved it ,i want to show the corresponding output of html tag

as an eg: string table="

```
  <table class="restbl">
    <tbody>
        <tr><th class="date">Date</th><th>Event</th><th>Host/City</th><th class="ven">Venue</th></tr>
        <tr><td class="date">Sun 11-Aug-2013</td><td>New Member Orientation Seminar</td><td >Koothattukulam</td><td class="ven"></td></tr>

   </tbody>
</table>"
```

how it possible.After retriving it is not shown the corresponding table.

Comment: You mean to say it's not rendered as HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose that you have a view model and in the Text property you have retrieved the HTML value from the database:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your view you could use the `@Html.Raw` helper to avoid the output to be automatically HTML encoded:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.Raw(Model.Text)
```

Needless to say that by doing this you are opening your site to XSS attacks if you do not sanitize the user input before outputing it. For example you could use the [`AntiXSS`](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
using System.Net;

string a = WebUtility.HtmlEncode("<html><head><title>T</title></head></html>");
string b = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(a);
```